# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java

this is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {


    private RadioButton r1;
    private RadioButton r2;
    private RadioButton r3;
    private RadioButton r4;
    private RadioButton r5;
    private RadioButton r6;
    private RadioGroup rg1;
    private RadioGroup rg2;
    private EditText v;
    private EditText v2;
    public Button button;
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r1);
        r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r2);
        r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r3);
        r4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r4);
        r5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r5);
        r6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r6);
        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        rg2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);
        v = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
        v2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        String[] unidades={"Volumen","Longitud","Masa","Temperatura"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> lista = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, unidades);
        spinner.setAdapter(lista);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        r1.setText("Litros");
                        r2.setText("MiliLitros");
                        r3.setText("Onzas");
                        r4.setText("Litros");
                        r5.setText("MiliLitros");
                        r6.setText("Onzas");


                        break;
                    case 1:
                        r1.setText("cm");
                        r2.setText("m");
                        r3.setText("Km");
                        r4.setText("cm");
                        r5.setText("m");
                        r6.setText("Km");

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        r1.setText("g");
                        r2.setText("Kg");
                        r3.setText("Lb");
                        r4.setText("g");
                        r5.setText("Kg");
                        r6.setText("Lb");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        r1.setText("Kelvin");
                        r2.setText("Farenhaith");
                        r3.setText("Centigrados");
                        r4.setText("Kelvin");
                        r5.setText("Farenhaith");
                        r6.setText("Centigrados");
                        break;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void onClick (View view){
        String selec=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (selec.equals("Volumen")) {
            if (r1.isChecked() && r5.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b*1000;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r1.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b*33.814;
                v2.setText((int)c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b/1000;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b*0.033814;
                v2.setText((int)c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b/33.814;
                v2.setText((int)c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r5.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b/0.033814;
                v2.setText((int)c);
            }
        }

        String selec1=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (selec1.equals("Longitud")) {
            if (r1.isChecked() && r5.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b / 100;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r1.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b / 100000;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b * 100;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b * 1000;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b * 100000;
                v2.setText(c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r5.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int c = b / 1000;
                v2.setText(c);
            }
        }


        String selec2=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (selec2.equals("Masa")){
            if (r1.isChecked() && r5.isChecked()) {
                String a= v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b*0.001;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }


            if (r1.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()) {
                String a= v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b*0.0022046;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()){
                String a= v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b/0.001;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()){
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b * 2.2046;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b / 0.0022046;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b / 2.2046;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }
        }

        String selec3=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (selec3.equals("Temperatura")){
            if (r1.isChecked() && r5.isChecked()) {
                String a= v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = (1.8*(b-273))+32;
                v2.setText((int)c);
            }


            if (r1.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()) {
                String a= v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b-273.15;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()){
                String a= v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = (b-32)/1.8;
                double d = c+273.15;
                v2.setText((int) d);
            }

            if (r2.isChecked() && r6.isChecked()){
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = (b-32)/1.8;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = b +273.15;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }

            if (r3.isChecked() && r4.isChecked()) {
                String a = v.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double c = (b*1.8)+32;
                v2.setText((int) c);
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.conversor, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


    }
}
```

---

//THIS IS THE ERROR:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.user.conversor, PID: 13477
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2710
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
    at com.example.user.conversor.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:118)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

//AND THIS IS DE XML CODE:

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Seleccionar"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Origen"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r1"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r2"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r3"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Destino"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rg2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp">



        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r4"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r5"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r6"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Convertir"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Valor"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/v"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please Help me, what is the problem???

Comment: post a proper question and if youhaven error post the stacktrace to it

Comment: One problem is that you haven't shown us the stacktrace ... or even the complete exception message.

Comment: The only text you posted is the title and "this is my code:". You will have to make a bit more efforts in explaining the problem if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the problem??

The explanation is on this line of the stacktrace:

Caused by: **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2710**

There is a resource missing.  If you look carefully at the line numbers in the stack trace and compare with the line number in your code, you should be able to identify the line that is fetching the resource.  That will tell you which resource is missing.

Comment: I do not understand you, that is, I can not identify the line of error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/89/exceptions-and-exception-handling/1815/creating-and-reading-stacktraces#t=201611172222230049711